# What is Inner and Outer Peace and how can I achieve them?

Tags: philosophy, meditation-practicalities

I am bit Confused about Inner and Outer Peace.

If they exist, how can I know and how can I achieve them?

Comment: What do you mean by outer peace?

Comment: Can you give a reference on where you saw this?

Answer (score 3):

Using Buddhist vocabulary, what you call "inner peace" might be "tranquility" (i.e. **[Passaddhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passaddhi)**); and what you call "Outer Peace" might be a consequence of ethical/virtuous/moral behaviour (i.e. **[Sīla](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/)**).

Answer (score 1):

[Viveka nissita](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/20.4-Vivekanissita-piya.pdf) (peace from solitude):

- Outer - seclusion or detachment from the sense doors, i.e., you do not delight any sensations or feelings born from external objects coming in contact with the respective faculties. Outer peace is achieve through the being eqaunimous and realising the impermanent nature of sensual experience. [Avijja Pahana Sutta 2](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/16.9-Avijja-Pahana-S-2-s35.80-piya.pdf)
- Inner - Absence of 5 hindrances. Overcoming the 5 hindrances is rather a long topic but the essay [Nīvaraṇa](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/32.1-Nivarana.-piya.pdf) by Piya Tan might give you the right pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Peace can only be achieved in two states.

- In a Dhyana
- In the state of an arahant

**In a Dhyana**

Dhyana means the peace you achieve through meditation.In this state of mind you are free from the chaos of the world and the mind. But this is temporary,when you loose Dhyana you will face chaos again.

**In the state of an arahant**

An arahant is a person who has gone beyond greed,lust,anger,They have achieved Nirvana. Their peace is permanent.

---

Other than in Hollywood movies we have not heard of peace having two sides.
In Buddhist reality there is no outside and inside. There is only the processes of the mind.

Simply put it,

MIND IS THE INSIDE AND OUTSIDE. To have peace one must have peace within, Once you have it there is no reason to worry about an Outer peace.

Here is a link to a book, It is free and you can read it online or save it to your device.Take your time and Read this.

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/khema/allofus.html#ch1

Answer (score 0):

Peace can be lost due to inner or outer reasons.

so, keep mindful on inner or outer obstacles.

when we feel inner weakness like anger, greed, hate etc. we lost our peace. We think these are due to outer reasons, but they are due to our (inner )weakness.